# Does LIMIT 1 still have effect on a unique column

Tags: mysql, performance, limits, unique-constraint

I know that adding `LIMIT 1` when searching for only one record makes a lot of difference when it comes to performance. But does it still have any effect when we search a column with a unique constraint?

Let us say I store email records with a `id` (int) primary key column and the `email` field is marked as unique. Do I still need to explicitly call `LIMIT 1` in my queries to speed up the returning of a result set? Or does the MySQL engine understand that as soon as one record is found the result can be returned since the field is marked as unique and is `LIMIT 1` obsolete?

MySQL table definition:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Email
(
    `id` int NOT NULL,
    `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE (`email`)
)
```

Does it in this case make a difference whether I do:

```
SELECT * WHERE `email`="john.doe@example.com";
```

Or

```
SELECT * WHERE `email`="john.doe@example.com" LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score -3):

if column has **unique index** (constraint), You do not need to use **LIMIT 1**

**LIMIT 1** - good tools for prevent potential errors when result MUST be single and You not sure about how many rows You have

Comment: The question was specifically about performance, i.e. whether adding `LIMIT 1` would make a `WHERE column = value` query any faster if `column` already has a `UNIQUE` constraint defined on it. The OP is well aware that the query would *definitely* return no more than one row anyway and `LIMIT 1` is unnecessary in terms of results. The question is whether `LIMIT 1` would help in that scenario in terms of performance.

Comment: the answer was on a first row - limit 1 do not improve performance in this case :-), a lot of time since 2015 when it was answered, but it not change the fact

Comment: No, that answer isn't on the first or any line of your post. That's something that one could *guess* from your response but not something you are saying explicitly. I mean, the OP was already guessing the same thing from the beginning, but they still weren't sure and decided to ask about it. In my view, when you are asking a question like that ("I kind of think this is so but I'm not sure. Is it?"), you are asking for some *evidence* either confirming or denying your guess. Of course, one is still perfectly free to just answer, "Yes, you are right" or "No, you are wrong" (or imply either). :)

Comment: look, generalyy it is not important, but if you decide to downgrade (may be you, or somebody after you lift it) the post after 4 years since it published .. it is a principal :-) - if column contain unique index you do not need to use LIMIT 1 FOR IMPROVE performnace ... this is exactly what was asked and what was answered!!! plus may be unnecessary part about where LIMIT 1 is good to use